# How to use ld --gc-sections with OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)

Tags: linker, ld

If my GNU ld linker script has `OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)` the `ld --gc-sections` command-line flag seems to be ignored:

`` $ cat gcs.c
extern void magic(void);
void callmagic(void) { magic(); }
int uanswer = 42;
int main(void) { return 0; }
$ cat ofbin.scr
OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS {
  . = 0x10000;
  .text : { *(.text*) }
  .data : { *(.data*) *(.rodata*) }
  .bss : { *(.bss*); }
}
$ cat ofelf.scr
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
OUTPUT_ARCH(i386)
ENTRY(main)
SECTIONS {
  . = 0x10000;
  .text : { *(.text*) }
  .data : { *(.data*) *(.rodata*) }
  .bss : { *(.bss*); }
}
$ gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs gcs.c -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections,--print-gc-sections -Wl,-T,ofelf.scr
/usr/bin/ld: Removing unused section '.text.callmagic' in file '/tmp/ccSFoPYg.o'
/usr/bin/ld: Removing unused section '.data.uanswer' in file '/tmp/ccSFoPYg.o'
/usr/bin/ld: Removing unused section '.eh_frame' in file '/tmp/ccSFoPYg.o'
$ gcc -m32 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs gcs.c -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections,--print-gc-sections -Wl,-T,ofbin.scr
/tmp/cceXCw2b.o: In function `callmagic':
gcs.c:(.text.callmagic+0x7): undefined reference to `magic'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ``

I'm using GNU ld 2.24 and GCC 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

How can I make this `.c` file compile and link with `OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)` and with the code of *callmagic* eliminated by `--gc-sections`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is impossible, and GNU ld ignores `--gc-sections` with `OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary)`.

A possible workaround is using `OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)` and post-processing the output ELF file, e.g. with `objcopy -O binary a.out a.out.bin`.